# Regular expression not none

Tags: python, regex

How to return a 'value', not None, when the regular expression doesn't match.
For example, I want second re.findall to return a list: [('a','b','value','d')] so that I can have a comparison between two strings. Here, The 'value' is best to be 'False' if possible.

```
import re
match = re.findall (r'(a)(b)(c)(d)','abcd')
print (match)
match = re.findall(r'(a)(b)(c)(d)','abd')
print (match)
```

output[1]:

> [('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')]

output[2]:

> []

Comment: If you want to return 'False', then .... return 'False'.  If you can't do that, we need to know _why_ so we can better help you.

Comment: Use capturing groups inside optional non-capturing groups: `r'(a)(b)(?:(c))?(d)'`

Comment: @Wiktor Stribizew Thanks. ? works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After observing that, in python, an empty list, `[]`, evaluates to False, this seems to be close to what you want:

```
>>> [re.findall(c,'abd') for c in 'abcd']
[['a'], ['b'], [], ['d']]
```

Or, if you are looking for the characters which match rather than the matches:

```
>>> [c if re.findall(c, 'abd') else False for c in 'abcd' ]
['a', 'b', False, 'd']
```

If you want the list of matches and you want `False` in place of `[]`, then:

```
>>> [x if x else False for x in (re.findall(c,'abd') for c in 'abcd')]
[['a'], ['b'], False, ['d']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do simply:

```
match = re.findall(r'(a?)(b?)(c?)(d?)','abd')
```

Note that this returns:

```
In [5]: re.findall(r'(a?)(b?)(c?)(d?)', 'abd')
Out[5]: [('a', 'b', '', 'd'), ('', '', '', '')]
```

That is, it both returns a blank for `'c'` (your desired condition) and all blanks for matching four missing characters.